# How fast would paper memos travel?

Tags: history

How fast would paper memos travel around an office? Between offices? How fast would it be expected for a response? How often would mailrooms deliver mail and similar items?

Comment: Depends a lot on the office type, urgency level, criticality of the job being done, etc.

Comment: Are you asking for historical references or speculation?

Comment: Historical references really. I mean, I'm not planning on building a cyberpunk world.

Comment: Also which time period?

Comment: Can be as recent as the new millennium. Or the eighties. Or the fifties. I'm not picky, because I can fudge the numbers for plot or whatever, and being too specific might exclude possible answers.

Comment: I agree, without more context this is too vague to answer. Also, at what point do "memos" which as such are pretty much a function of typewriters end, and letters and journals which were much more common before then, begin. At the height of the age of letters, it wouldn't be unheard of for an urban man of affairs to get mail deliveries seven times a day.

Comment: Too bad about the request for historical data.  I was really looking forward to some scientific analysis regarding the maximum velocity of a tungstun-wrapped message pod when launched from a cannon for crosstown (or trans-continental) delivery.  Though it might be more of a *steampunk* solution than a *cyberpunk* one, since the latter genre favors email over snail mail.

Comment: I once took a Six Sigma course, and one example the instructor used was observing a requisition form take *three months* to move through a single office in a city bureaucracy which was being monitored by the instructor as part of a consulting job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where I work we do most communications by mail or other electronic systems. There are exceptions, mostly for incoming paper mail and for forms which must be signed (invoices, payment authorizations, ...).

- Each department has a room with mail slots. Each employee is supposed to check the box roughly once a workday. People who hardly ever get mail will check it once every two or three days.
- The mail clerks come once a workday to fill the "in" boxes of the employees and to empty the "out" box for sorting. The "out" messages get delivered on the next round.

That means an inhouse letter can take up to three days -- into the '"out" box just after the mail clerk came around, collected the next day, delivered a day after that, and the recipient might get it the next morning.

If we want faster response time, the only way is to hand-carry the message ourselves. That's usually **faster than electronic mail**, because a guy standing in the doorway gets a higher priority than a message on the computer screen. Of course this speed depends on the "surprise value" of a hand-carried message. If it was common, people would insist on using their "in" tray. (The IT department tries to insist that every support request goes through their electronic system.)

We have special courier delivery once a workday to some of our suppliers once a workday. The receptionist has a special "out" box, it is the responsibility of the sender to get the letter there on schedule.

By contrast, there are organizations which have developed the timely handling of physical messages to a fine art. A court building might empty their "in" box on midnight and stamp the letters with the arrival date to set them apart from letters arriving after midnight (possibly too late).

Answer (score 4):

I was regularly in a newsroom growing up with pneumatic tubes connected all the floors in the 7 story building. The system was built shortly after WWII, I think, but I've seen buildings as old as late 1800s in London that had the tubes. Might be older. Write a note and put someone's name on the outside then put it in the slot for the right floor and whoosh! Off it went. A secretary on that floor was constantly monitoring for incoming tubes and handing them to runners to take around the floor. This allowed reporters to ask for a fact check from the archives or for a late edit to be sent to the printing press. It was all pretty quick as long as you were messaging within the same building.

Comment: Just the fact that you mention *fact-checks before print* makes me wonder where over the last 50yrs that mentality got lost in journalists

Comment: It's still there among journalists. Most of the people you see on TV/Internet/publications are *entertainers*.